# How to write a function or loop to replace binary value with column name?

Tags: r

I am still new to R, and I run into this task to transform the df which I cannot solve.

I have a data frame, which I am trying to replace value of 1 (for each row) by its column name.

```
ID flag1 flag2 flag3 flag4
a1   1     0     1     1
a2   0     1     0     0
```

```
    df <- data.frame("ID"=c("a1","a2"), 
                      "flag1" = c(1,0),
                      "flag2" = c(0,1),
                      "flag3" = c(1,1),
                      "flag4" = c(1,1))
```

I understand that I will have to create a function and/or loop to accomplish my goal.

I am looking to transform the dataframe to the following

```
ID Name
a1 flag1
a1 flag3
a1 flag4
a2 flag2
```

Thank you for any help/hint.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tidyverse approach, which treats this as a reshaping task, where we want the column names to the right of `ID` to be pulled into a single new variable, and we just want to keep the `1`'s.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  gather(col, val, -ID) %>%
  filter(val == 1) %>%
  arrange(ID, col) %>%  # optional, just to sort
  select(-val)          # optional, just to remove col of 1's

  ID   col
1 a1 flag1
2 a1 flag3
3 a1 flag4
4 a2 flag2
5 a2 flag3
6 a2 flag4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is exactly what I was trying to get to. Any hint on how I can solve this with a function or loop as I am working on trying to get better at these too

Answer (score 0):

Using 'melt' from 'data.table'

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame("ID"=c("a1","a2"), 
                     "flag1" = c(1,0),
                     "flag2" = c(0,1),
                     "flag3" = c(1,1),
                     "flag4" = c(1,1))

df <- as.data.table(df)
df2 <- melt(df, id="ID")[value==1][, value:=NULL]
df2

   ID variable
1: a1    flag1
2: a2    flag2
3: a1    flag3
4: a2    flag3
5: a1    flag4
6: a2    flag4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The code is so clean and easy to understand